# JQuery .load requires reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started using JQuery in my project today. I messed around with it on Codecademy, though.

I use the `.load()` function on my site, because loading webpages is a little bit faster, and it's easier for me in the long run. I'm having a problem with my code, where when I click a link to a page, it goes blank. I then have to reload to see it. Here's my JQuery:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
    } else {
    alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
  }
}

var main = function() {

    if(pathname === "cards%20gh-pages/index") {
        ChangeUrl("Index", "index");
        $('body').load("index.html #body");
    } else if(pathname === "cards%20gh-pages/nav-drawer") {
        ChangeUrl("Nav-Drawer", "nav-drawer");
        $('body').load("nav-drawer.html #body");
    }

    $('#index-link').click(function() {
        ChangeUrl("Index", "index");
        $('body').load("index.html #body");
    });

    $('#nav-drawer-link').click(function() {
        ChangeUrl("Nav-Drawer", "nav-drawer");
        $('body').load("nav-drawer.html #body");
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

If I click the nav drawer link, it goes to `xyz/nav-drawer` and if I click the index link, it goes to `xyz/index`. Either way, it's the same issue stated above. Any help with this would be nice.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ohmvgw19/1/
The html portion is the same across the files.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="card header">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="index-link">Horizontal Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a id="nav-drawer-link">Vertical Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="color" id="color-link">Color</a></li>
                <li last><a href="tables" id="tabels-link">Tables</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: SHow the corresponding html for these.

Comment: @charlietfl https://jsfiddle.net/ohmvgw19/1/

Comment: should include the relevant html snippets in question also. Questions should be self contained...demos are great additions though

Answer (score 0):

The href's in the `<a>` tags are why you are having issues.

When you click on one and browser sees the href the default behavior is to load the url that it understands that href to be.

So you would need to prevent that default behavior when you are over riding it.

An event handler like a click handler is not over riding the default, it is simply intercepting it and unless told to cancel the default behavior will occur after the code within your event handler is done

Try this:

```
$('#nav-drawer-link').click(function(event) {
   // "event" is a complex object with many properties
   event.preventDefault();

   ChangeUrl("Nav-Drawer", "nav-drawer");
   $('body').load("nav-drawer.html #body");

});
```

the same principles apply to many other events....form submit, key events, other mouse events, touch events etc

Comment: The two links that are still normal aren't the issue. I've had similar code work, it's something about the pathname "if" statements, I think.

Comment: shouldn't have a `%20` that's a space. Spaces are horrible in url's. Use your console to log the actual pathname `console.log(pathname)` and see what it actually is. Should have a leading`/` in it